# Android not reading Firebase database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I'm quite new to Android and this thing is driving me nuts. The thing is, in my app I have a login based on Firebase Auth, using email/password. I wanted to add a username for each registered user, and it went well.

The problem is when I try to read the username from the database, which returns `null`.

This is the database:

[image: Database]

And this is my code to try to read the `username` field:

```
private FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
private DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());

private TextView uid, mail, username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid());
    uid = findViewById(R.id.userID);
    mail = findViewById(R.id.Mail);
    username = findViewById(R.id.userPerfil);

    userRef.child("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

As you can see, the dataSnapshot reads the key correctly, but not the value.

[image: here]

Comment: `userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid());` should have `child("Users")` before the userid

Comment: you are getting the same instance two time once 
`private DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());` and second time in the `onCreate` method 
`userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid());` so I think you are not giving the User in the second time like this `getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());` tell me when you try this.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thank you very much! I know it's kinda dumb to have forgotten this, but after any hours I guess I was too tired.

Comment: make sure user.getUid() is returning right value !

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, you can use UpdateProfileChangeRequest to save the username.

Take a look at the code below, I used the same for my app:

```
FirebaseUser mCurrentUser=mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
UserProfileChangeRequest userProfileChangeRequest= new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(signUpUsername)
                                    .build();
if (mCurrentUser != null) {
    mCurrentUser.updateProfile(userProfileChangeRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this,"Username Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And use the following code to retrieve the username:

```
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser=mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
  String username=firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
```

Hope this helps:)